# ExcelReaderFactory, reading from SftpFileStream

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net, exceldatareader

I am getting an error while reading a .xlsx file using `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(streamReader)` and stream reader is a `SftpFileStream` (`SftpClient.OpenRead(filePath)`).

The error message i am getting is

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException: General failure

I am not able to get through the first line of code.

```
using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(streamReader))
{
     //Get reader as DataSet
     var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
     {
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
           UseHeaderRow = true
        }
                    });
.......
}
```

But when I use the code using `System.IO.File.Open` then it works fine.

Stack:

```
at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestRead(Byte[] handle, UInt64 offset, UInt32 length)
   at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipHelper.ReadBytes(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bytesToRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipHelper.SeekBackwardsAndRead(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32& bufferPointer)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipHelper.SeekBackwardsToSignature(Stream stream, UInt32 signatureToFind)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at ExcelDataReader.Core.ZipWorker..ctor(Stream fileStream)
   at ExcelDataReader.ExcelOpenXmlReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(Stream fileStream, ExcelReaderConfiguration configuration)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is obviously a bug in `SftpFileStream.Seek` code. When called with `SeekOrigin.End`, it substracts the `offset` from the position of the end of the file, rather than adding it.

If you can modify SSH.NET code, change both instances of this statement in `SftpFileStream.Seek`:

```
newPosn = attributes.Size - offset;
```

to

```
newPosn = attributes.Size + offset;
```

I've submitted a [pull request with this fix](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/pull/508) to the SSH.NET repository.

---

If you cannot change the SSH.NET code, you will have to workaround that.

1. Either copy the `SftpFileStream` contents to a temporary `MemoryStream` and use that with `ExcelReaderFactory`.

   ```
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sftpFileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memoryStream))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
   ```
2. Or if you do not want to waste memory holding another copy of the file, you can implement own `Stream` wrapper around  `SftpFileStream`, which translates `SeekOrigin.End` to `SeekOrigin.Begin` with a proper `offset`.

   For an example of such implementation, see:
   [List files inside ZIP file located on SFTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63991495/850848)

---

*Note that `ZipArchive` (internally used by `ExcelReaderFactory`) uses `Stream.Seek` with `SeekOrigin.End`, because ZIP central directory is at the end of the ZIP file. – XLSX file is basically a ZIP file with a specific structure.*