# Count files in a ZIP file over SFTP using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, zip, sftp

I am connecting to SFTP via host, port, username and password using PowerShell. I want to count the number of files in a particular zip folder without having to download the zip folder on my local machine and count. Please share the piece of logic that would do this. I looked into this but it seems a bit tricky when it comes to do this in a zip folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an easy task to do. There's no API in SFTP to do that completely remotely. There are basically two solutions:

1. Use SFTP to download only the ZIP central directory (basically the listing that is placed at the very end of the ZIP file). And decode the directory locally. For C#, this is covered in my answer to [List files inside ZIP file located on SFTP server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63991495/850848). Though as mentioned there, there's a bug in SSH.NET that requires a workaround with implementing an interface. While that's probably [doable in PowerShell too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32065124/850848), I've never done that.
2. If you have an SSH shell access to the server, use remote `zip` command to list the contents of the file. Or build another API (like a web service).

---

Btw, note that there's nothing like ZIP *"folder"*. ZIP is an archive *file*. It's only Windows that *call* ZIP files *"folders"*.